# Ajax Url to Routed WCF in Asp.Net 4 Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, asp.net-routing

I implemented Routing in Asp.Net 4 Web App.
With aspx file it works fine, but it doesn't work with WCF.

I have WCF which is called from javascipt file by ajax request.

My WCF code is:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Signature
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get signature info by email address.
        /// </summary>        
        [OperationContract]        
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string GetSignatureInfo(string email)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Web.config:

```
<services>     
  <service name="WEB.Services.Signature">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WEB.Services.SignatureAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WEB.Services.Signature" />
  </service>
</services>
```

---

javascript:

```
var _data = {
    "email": self.email.val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: '../Signature'
    , type: 'POST'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , data: JSON.stringify(_data)
    , success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
    , error: function () {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

---

Global.asax:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var sr = new ServiceRoute("Signature", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Signature));
    sr.Url = "Services/Signature.svc/GetSignatureInfo";
    routes.Add(sr);
}


void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            
}
```

I get "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - _http://www.my-project.com/Signature". Where am I wrong or what ajax url should be ?!!! Please, help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you hit "Post your question" without having finished it. You can edit the question to add the code you were going to add and also your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed now

Comment: Try fully qualifying the URL you're passing in the JavaScript - instead of `url: '../Signature'` use `url: 'http://somedomain/url: '../Signature'`.  Also, your method takes a parameter, so you probably need to pass that in as well.

Answer (score 3):

My work colleague has found a solution:
The problem was in IIS configuration - 
If my app is under Default Site , I should add ajax url with prefix of project. For example, if my Service is located in Web project, I should enter url like : '/Web/Services/MyService/MyFunction' in js file. The same url should be on Global.asax file, in ServiceRoute url, but without first '/'.
In this case, it will work fine locally,but there will be a problem to put it on production server.

The optimal solution:
1. IIS : add web site, configure physical path to him, change its port(!!!).
2. .js + Global.asax : just remove project name from url in both places. So, the url will be like :  in js file '/Services/MyService/MyFunction' and in Global.asax 'Services/MyService/MyFunction' (without first '/')

That's all. Big thanks to Miri(colleague).